# Make newest item on top in To Do List using Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a problem with my todo list. I want when I input a new item, it appears on top of list items, not below the list items. I have put `track by -$index` but it doesn't work

index.html snippet

```
<ul class="unstyled">
   <li ng-repeat="todo in todos track by -$index">
       <input type="checkbox" ng-model="todo.done">
       <span class="done-{{todo.done}}">{{todo.text}}</span>
    </li>
</ul>
```

controller.js snippet

```
app.controller('TodoListController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.todos = [];

    $scope.addTodo = function() {
        $scope.todos.push({text:$scope.todoText, done:false});
        $scope.todoText = '';
    };
```

Are there any solution for this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`unshift()`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_unshift.asp) to prepend the items to your array instead of `push()` and remove your `track by -$index`

Javascript

```
app.controller('TodoListController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.todos = [];

    $scope.addTodo = function() {
        $scope.todos.unshift({text:$scope.todoText, done:false});
        $scope.todoText = '';
    };
```

HTML

```
<ul class="unstyled">
   <li ng-repeat="todo in todos">
       <input type="checkbox" ng-model="todo.done">
       <span class="done-{{todo.done}}">{{todo.text}}</span>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: At the moment it appears on top of the list. It also appears on top of previous items or am i wrong?

Comment: Why should it be a,b,d,c? The item is now on top of nothing. d,a,b,c would mean the item is on top of the list..

Comment: @AnikIslamAbhi I am sorry about the words. I means on top of the list

Comment: @AnikIslamAbhi By the way, thanks for your answer because your answer will be useful too

Answer (score 1):

The solution from @nipeco works fine but it changes the logic for presentation purposes which personally I wouldn't recommend.

I think it's best to push and use the filter orderBy+reverse to have the desired output.

```
<li ng-repeat="todo in todos | orderBy:'-$index':reverse">
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: You're right ! But why must we use `-$index` instead of `$index` ?

Comment: You're right, changing logic for presentation is bad! :)